# How to partition boolean functions into CCZ(Carlet-Charpin-Zinovlev) equivalent classes

Tags: finite-fields, boolean-algebra

I'm doing some exercises for my course on Finite fields, and have a question regarding boolean functions.

The question gives me several (7,7) functions and asks me to partition them into CCZ equivalent classes (find all pairs among the given functions that are CCZ eqivalent).

The functions are:

f<sub>1</sub>(x) = x<sup>10</sup>

f<sub>2</sub>(x) = x<sup>23</sup>

f<sub>3</sub>(x) = x<sup>25</sup>

f<sub>4</sub>(x) = x<sup>40</sup>

f<sub>5</sub>(x) = x<sup>101</sup>

The problem I have is that I can't really find any examples on how this is done. Any pointers or guidance is appreciated!

Edit: CCZ stands
Carlet-Charpin-Zinovlev equivalent. Two $(n, m)$-functions $F$ and $G$ are CCZ-equivalent if there is an affine permutation which maps the graph $\{(x, F(x)) : x \in \Bbb{F}_{2^n} \}$ of $F$ to the graph of $G$.

Comment: Explain what CCZ stand for...

Comment: Carlet-Charpin-Zinovlev equivalent. Two (n, m)-functions F and G
are CCZ-equivalent if there is an affine permutation which maps the graph
{(x, F(x)) : x ∈ F2n } of F to the graph of G.

Comment: Zinovlev or Zinoview? I have met both Claude Carlet and Pascale Charpin. And Victor Zinoview (father), I haven't met Dmitri Zinoview (son, works in France), but I have coauthored a paper with him! Meaning that I may be able to help :-)

Comment: Hint: $f_1(x^4)=f_4(x)$ for all $x\in K=\Bbb{F}_{128}$. Calculate $f_2(x^{32})$.

Comment: And look up *cyclotomic cosets*.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it